# Why can't the iPhone take a photo at the maximum supported ISO?

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, iso, avcapturedevice, iphone7plus

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH107-SW14), the iPhone 7 Plus back camera (the wide one) can take photos at up to an ISO of 1716. But when I try to take a photo at that ISO, I instead get 1600.

I tried printing AVCaptureDevice.activeFormat!.maxISO, and it's indeed 1716.

I tried this with a third-party app (ProCamera), and the same problem manifests there.

How do I take a photo at ISO 1716?